# my express +socket.io start in two different ports

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, socket.io

my express 4 application always starts at port 3000 (socketIO is ignored in this port) 
when i explicitely listen a to a different  port after binding my express app with socket.io .
express +socket start on the port i have set (let's say :3030) i can run my app in both ports .port 3000 doesn't take into account socket.io and 3030 takes it into account .
localy i have no issues with that , but once i push my project to heroku , i get

> EADDRINUSE Address already in use

here is my configuration

```
    {
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {


    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
        "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
        "morgan": "~1.0.0",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
        "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
        "debug": "~0.7.4",
        "jade": "*",
        "ejs": "*",
        "mongodb": "*",
        "mongoskin": "*",
        "monk": "*",
        "passport" : "*", 
        "passport-facebook":"*",   
        "passport-local" : "~0.1.6",  
        "passport-facebook" : "~1.0.2", 
        "passport-twitter" : "~1.0.2",  
        "passport-google-oauth" : "~0.1.5",  
        "bcrypt-nodejs" : "latest"  ,              
        "mongoose" : "~3.8.1",           
        "express": "~4.0.0",
        "method-override": "~1.0.0",
        "express-session" : "*",
        "socket.io": ">= 0.9.6"
    }
}
```

my app.js

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
http.listen(3030,
  function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});


module.exports = app;
```

the www script!

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('my-application');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Can you add your code? Especially the lines that use the port numbers (3000, 3030).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have two ports open in Heroku.

Comment: What does bin/www contain?

Comment: Also where do you define app?

Comment: the www script listens to port 3000 i think that's what is wrong .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843674/how-to-start-node-express-binaryserver-and-socket-io-on-same-port
Look at this link it has code to run express and socket on same port

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by setting  "start": "node app" to avoid starting in to different ports , so i completely got ride of the wwww script in ./bin , and then i used this command `heroku ps:scale web=1` to overcome the H14 error .