# How to start node express, binaryserver and socket.io on same port?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have code snippet to explain what i am doing and what i want.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var server = http.createServer(app);

var binaryServer = new BinaryServer({server:server});


var ioServer = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(ioServer);
```

I can run node express and socket.io on same port.

```
ioServer.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('server running at localhost:8080');
});
```

Same can be done with node express and binaryServer.

```
server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('server running at localhost:8080');
});
```

But i want to run node express, socket.io and binaryServer on same port express is running (8080 in this case).
Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can't  run 2 services on same port. you have to specify separate port for it.

Comment: @Deepak Sharma - i can run 2 services on same port as shown in above code. But i want to run more than 2 services on same port

Comment: Socket.io supports binary transfer.

Comment: @Ben Fortune - Thanks for the suggestion but i don't want to change my written code.

Comment: The binary server package is completely redundant.

Comment: Good to know that i have to change it. Thanks, but is there any way to run more than 2 services on same port in nodejs. (Longing to know for my knowledge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to attach both the SocketIO and binaryServer to same http `server` instance then bring that single instance up.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var binaryServer = new BinaryServer({ server:server, path: '/binary'});

server.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('http/socket/binary server running at localhost:8080');
});
```

Set the `path` so binaryServer doesn't conflict with any of your apps. This path is required in the client connections too.